Pine Script: use request.security with resources from the restricted indicator
How can I use "request.security" without knowing the indicator code for the expression argument? I take data for my indicator through the "input" function. It is necessary to know the indicator value on the 5M timeframe, but the "request.security" function provides data only from the current timeframe due to the fact that I cannot describe the action for the "expression" argument in the form of code
indicator("Mooving_5m", overlay = true, timeframe = "5")
a = input.source(close, "a")

b = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", a)
plot(b, color = color.blue)


This is expected, the request.security() function will not switch the context of the calculation to another timeframe of an external source imported with input.source(), it will be calculated in the context of the currently selected chart timeframe only.
